# Why google does not index links inside a page

Tags: seo, web-crawler, history.js, hashbang

When I submit following page http://www.cru.do/issues/1/?contents for indexing I would expect that google crawler grabs all links inside element

```
<section id="contents-list">
<nav id="list">
```

they all look following way: `<a href="http://www.cru.do/issues/1/?dom">Dominic Lord</a>`

so there should be no problem with hash url etc. and thanks to History.js there is no need for hashbangs

it all works great except that those inside page links are not being indexed by google

Answer (score 0):

First, read these: 
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/09/dynamic-urls-vs-static-urls.html
http://moz.com/blog/dynamic-urls-vs-static-urls-the-best-practice-for-seo-is-still-clear

Looking at the contents of site:http://www.cru.do/ I see that the title and description google is displaying are all the same. For example, http://www.cru.do/issues/1/?gashi should show the unique version of the title and content but it doesn't, it looks the same as the others. Now that page is also the third down in the list of links so, it may be a matter of time, or Google has stopped indexing those links since they don't appear to be unique content. The site looks young, so it could be a matter of time.

I also don't see a sitemap.xml file reference, so if you haven't submitted one (one way is through google webmasters) then I would suggest you do that.

I personally, haven't had great luck with dynamic urls, so I can't offer much help in the url structure except to say look at another older site with the same type of url and see how google has indexed it.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I think that it will be better to change link http://www.cru.do/issues/1/?gashi -> http://www.cru.do/issues/1/?article=gashi. But the biggest problem from my view is that the page is  still the same (content is changed by JS) and google evalute all those links as duplicates because in the end they point to the same page. What do you think ?